# Python undefined variable issue

Tags: python, indexing, undefined

During python programming, i met an undefined error.

The error is about 'flag' variable and i can use it in the above print sentence without any error.

Why the error occur only for index of array?

If you have any ideas, please share it for me.

Thank you for your interest.

```
class Solution:
    def rob(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        global memo
        
        memo = [[0 for j in range(len(nums))] for i in range(2)]
        flag = 0
        #print("===========================")
        def dp(i : int) -> int:
            global flag
            
            if i >= len(nums):
                #print(i,"return 0")
                return 0

            if i == 1:
                flag = 1
                #print(str(i) + " : " + str(globals), memo)

            if memo[flag][i] is not 0: # <= undefined error occur because of flag
                #print(i,"*",memo)
                return memo[i]
            memo[i] = max(dp(i+1), (dp(i+2) + nums[i]))
            if i is len(nums) - 1 and i is not 0:
                result = nums[i] * flag
                flag = 0
                #print(str(i) + " ! " , result)
                return result
            #print(i,"-",memo)
            return memo[i]
        return max(dp(0), dp(1))
```

```
NameError: name 'flag' is not defined. Did you mean: 'flags'?
    if memo[flag][i] is not 0:
Line 21 in dp (Solution.py)
    return max(dp(0), dp(1))
Line 37 in rob (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().rob(param_1)
Line 57 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 68 in <module> (Solution.py)
  if i is len(nums) - 1 and i is not 0:
  if memo[flag][i] is not 0:
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `!=` instead of `is not`?

Comment: @kmoser no, it's python. `is not` is the same as `!=`

Comment: They're the same for small integers, but I don't think you should depend on that.

Comment: Well, @JoeyM `is not` accomplish what is required but how it is using here is not 'best way' because is recommended when you try to compare with None not with 0.

Comment: @JoeyM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe

Comment: Oh wow @kmoser I didn't know this. 4th year Python programmer and still learning every day

Comment: @JoeyM Python is not English, or in Python: `"python != "english"`. `is not` compares object identity, while `!=` compares object contents.

Comment: @Barmar "They're the same for small integers, but I don't think you should depend on that." - and that optimization is only true for CPython, making your recommendation to not depend on it so much more valuable.

Comment: @JoeyM **absolutely not**. `is not` and `!=` are *entirely different thigns

Comment: @Barmar no, it is not the same for small integers. It is never the same

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `global` at all

Comment: Noted, @SethMMorton thank you so much. This will definitely help me in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem happens because you have a function inside another function so `global` key word won't work. There are four scopes in Python: Local, Enclose, Global and Built-in and `rob` function is in Enclose scope, so what you have to do is change for `nonlocal` key word as following:

```
def dp(i : int) -> int:
    nonlocal flag

    if i >= len(nums):
       #print(i,"return 0")
       return 0
```

BTW using `local` or `nonlocal` aren't recommended so try to use in other way.

Comment: Oh i see. now i've solved my problems. thank you for providing keywords.